# error when performing unit test on exception with matlab test framework

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, exception

I've the following class in folder `+WTrade/+Database/@PostgreSQLConnectionOptions`:

```matlab
classdef PostgreSQLConnectionOptions < handle

  properties (Access = private)
    databaseHost
  end

  methods (Access = public)

    function this = PostgreSQLConnectionOptions()
      this.databaseHost = "";
    end

    function setHostname(this, name)
      if ~isstring(name)
        me = MException("WTrade:invalidParameter", "WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOption.setHostname: name must be a string");
        throw(me);
      end
      if 1 ~= length(name)
        me = MException("WTrade:invalidParameter", "WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOption.setHostname: name array size must be 1");
        throw(me);
      end

      this.databaseHost = name;
    end

  end
end
```

I want to perform a unit test on this class. I've the following test class

```matlab
classdef PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

  methods (Test)

    function testWrongHostnameArray(this)
      options = WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions();
      hostName = ["h1" "h2"];
      this.verifyError(options.setHostname(hostName), 'WTrade:invalidParameter');
    end

  end
end
```

When I try to run the test with following script:

```matlab
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite
import matlab.unittest.constraints.Throws;

databaseSuite = TestSuite.fromFolder("tests/WTrade/Database");
result = run(databaseSuite);
```

I obtain the following error:

```
>> runtests('PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest','ProcedureName','testWrongHostnameArray')
Running PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest
32        options = WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions();

================================================================================
Error occurred in PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest/testWrongHostnameArray and it did not run to completion.
    ---------
    Error ID:
    ---------
    'MATLAB:TooManyOutputs'
    --------------
    Error Details:
    --------------
    Error using WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions/setHostname
    Too many output arguments.

    Error in PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest/testWrongHostnameArray (line 34)
          this.verifyError(options.setHostname(hostName), 'WTrade:invalidParameter');
================================================================================
.
Done PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest
__________

Failure Summary:

     Name                                                    Failed  Incomplete  Reason(s)
    =======================================================================================
     PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest/testWrongHostnameArray    X         X       Errored.

ans = 

  TestResult with properties:

          Name: 'PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest/testWrongHostnameArray'
        Passed: 0
        Failed: 1
    Incomplete: 1
      Duration: 2.0606
       Details: [1×1 struct]

Totals:
   0 Passed, 1 Failed (rerun), 1 Incomplete.
   2.0606 seconds testing time.
```

I don't understand the `'MATLAB:TooManyOutputs'` error. I've tried the method directly in matlab and it works as expected; I test if the argument is a string and if it's not the case it launches an exception.

When I run the following command:

```matlab
a = WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions
a.setHostname(["p1", "p2")
```

I obtain the error that I'm expecting.

```
Error using WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions/setHostname (line 43)
WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOption.setHostname: name array size must be 1
```

So why I'm not able to catch the exception correctly in the test case? How can I check correctly that I throw the exception so I can pass the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function handle to verifyError. What is happening now is you are calling `this.verifyError(options.setHostname(hostName), 'WTrade:invalidParameter');` which is actually invoking `options.setHostname(hostName)` with one output argument to pass as an argument to verifyError. Instead it should be:

`this.verifyError(@() options.setHostname(hostName), 'WTrade:invalidParameter');`

Also, I would recommend using a standard property `Hostname` and instead of writing a setter method use the validation syntax, like so:

```
classdef PostgreSQLConnectionOptions < handle

  properties 
    Hostname(1,1) string = "";
  end

end
```

Not, if you need to do more custom validation you can always write a setter method like so:

```
methods
    function set.Hostname(options, hostname)
        % some additional validation here
    end
end
```

Note though when you use the properties, in order to use verifyError you'll need to wrap it in a function:

```
classdef PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

  methods (Test)

    function testWrongHostnameArray(this)
      options = WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions();
      hostName = ["h1" "h2"];
      this.verifyError(@setHostname, 'WTrade:invalidParameter');
      function setHostname
          options.Hostname = hostname;
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Even though you need to wrap this in a function for testing, it is by and large a better experience to use properties as they are. We have [built in encapsulation with matlab](https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2016/08/08/han-solo-encapsulation/), and I think it's best to leverage it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check the solution ASAP. For the encapsulation: the code is different from this one, I adapted it only in order to show the problem.